# Where did locate current file button in Solution Explorer has gone in new VS2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've reinstalled VS2019 and I can't find button in Solution Explorer that locates currently open file. Where it is gone, how to restore it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old question but I was just searching for the same and found the answer: the button is still there but it got a different icon after the recent update.

It's called "*Sync with Active Document*", an icon with blue circular arrows. Its shortcut is `Ctrl+[, S`.

Note that this button is only visible if "*Track Active Item in Solution Explorer*" checkbox is disabled in Visual Studio settings.

Comment: This is still valid in VS 2022, but now the icon is more circular. The shortcut is the same.

Comment: @Andacious In my VS 2022 the icon is more flat. It's now just two flat lines, e.g. "⥦"

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2022 it's the button with back/forward arrows:
[image: Visual Studio 2022 Solution Explorer bar with sync file button]